# Android equivalent code for iOS protocol implemented parameter

Tags: android, ios

When I need a specific object that implements a protocol in iOS, I write:

```
-(void)someMethodWithObject:(SpecificObjectType<SomeProtocol>) object;
```

Is there an Android equivalence for this code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, in Java (Android main language), you will do that with Interface:

1. Create an Interface (SomeProtocol)

   `public interface SomeProtocol {
       public void someMethodWithObject();
   }`
2. Create an object that implements the Interface

   `public class SepcificObjectType implements SomeProtocol {
       public void someMethodWithObject() {
           // Implement your logic here
       }
   }`

Comment: Wondering if you had a chance to try my answer. Please vote the answer if it helps.

Comment: I was not sure how do this using interfaces, but it's working now. Thanks @Mei-Lin